# After Capistrano deploy my images uploaded via shrine arent displayed anymore (Rails + SQlite3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, shrine

When i try to deploy my new application, everything went smooth. But i used to had the problem that my posts in my db disappear after a capistrano deploy. I found out, that this has to do with my Sqlite3 DB and that i have to add the shared path for production in my database.yml. Thats why i added:

```
    production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: /home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/releases/shared/db/production.sqlite3
```

now my posts stay also after a cap deploy, but my images arent showing of anymore. I guess i have to put them, or link them somehow to that folder aswell but iam not sure how.
My shrine.rb looks like that:

```
 require 'shrine'
require 'shrine/storage/file_system'

Shrine.storages = {
    # temporary storage
    cache: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new('public', prefix: 'uploads/cache'),
    enter code here
    # permanent storage
    store: Shrine::Storage::FileSystem.new('public', prefix: 'uploads/store'),
}

Shrine.plugin :activerecord
Shrine.plugin :cached_attachment_data # for forms
```

changing uploads/cache to `/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/releases/shared/uploads/cache`

and uploads/store to

```
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/releases/shared/uploads/store
```

doesnt seem to fix the problem ... Any ideas ?

Comment: Iam using Rails 5.2.0 and deploying it on DO if thats an important info

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/current/public` and check with `ls -l` if you have a link to `/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/releases/shared/uploads`.

When you add custom folders to a /shared, you have to tell capistrano to symlink them, but you need a little change.

First, change the paths to `/shared/public`

```
/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/releases/shared/public/uploads
```

Now, add this to your deploy.rb

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, [])+%W{public/uploads}
```

Now, after a deploy, capistrano will create a symlink from `current/public/uploads` to `shared/public/uploads`.

Comment: so i guess i have to do ln -s /home/deploy/apps/Bloggapp/current/public/ /home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/public/uploads if the links isnt existing right? only my asset folder hast a link to /home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/shared/public/assets - the terminal says if i run the command above that the file exists. Which paths do i have to change? so instead of public shared/public ?

Comment: You said you upload the files to `/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/releases/shared/uploads/store`, you should upload them to `/home/deploy/apps/Blogapp/releases/shared/public/uploads/store`, same with `cache`. You don't need to excecute the `ln` command, if you set capistrano's `linked_dirs` option, capistrano does that for you.